# In GLSL Shader, how to move an image 'smoothly' without 'scrubbing'

Tags: java, glsl, shader, processing

In particular I am using a Processing Java example that makes use of a GLSL shader (it's called InfiniteTiles).  The original sketch is actually just moving a tiled image.

I have a uniform variable called time that I call in java.

```
tileShader.set("time", millis() / 1000.0);
```

Now in the fragment shader there is a code section

```
vec2 pos = gl_FragCoord.xy - vec2(TILES_COUNT_X * time);
vec2 p = (resolution - TILES_COUNT_X * pos) / resolution.x;
vec3 col = texture2D (tileImage, p).xyz;
```

What I attempted to do in the java code is set the time variable such that I might be able to increase and decrease the speed at which the image scrolls.

I wrote this

```
float t =millis() / 1000.0;
float pctX = map (mouseX, 0, width, 0, 1);
tileShader.set("time", t*pctX);
```

What happens is that when I move the mouse, the entire image moves rapidly either left or right depending on where im moving as if its like 'scrubbing' the image.  When i stop moving the mouse, then it will move at the desired speed.

I would like to avoid this 'scrubbing' effect and have the image scrolling speed transition smoothly with the mouse movement.

Normally I could accomplish such a thing with just drawing an image in java and scrolling it, but I think I'm not understanding something fundamental about the way glsl works to achieve the same effect on the graphics card.

Any help appreciated.

Full processing code from example:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------
// Display endless moving background using a tile texture.
// Contributed by martiSteiger
//-------------------------------------------------------------

PImage tileTexture;
PShader tileShader;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480, P2D);
  textureWrap(REPEAT);
  tileTexture = loadImage("penrose.jpg");
  loadTileShader();
}

void loadTileShader() {  
  tileShader = loadShader("scroller.glsl");
  tileShader.set("resolution", float(width), float(height));  
  tileShader.set("tileImage", tileTexture);
}

void draw() {
  tileShader.set("time", millis() / 1000.0);
  shader(tileShader);                    
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Full Shader code

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
// Display endless moving background using a tile texture.
// Contributed by martiSteiger
//---------------------------------------------------------

uniform float time;
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform sampler2D tileImage;

#define TILES_COUNT_X 4.0

void main() {
  vec2 pos = gl_FragCoord.xy - vec2(4.0 * time);
  vec2 p = (resolution - TILES_COUNT_X * pos) / resolution.x;
  vec3 col = texture2D (tileImage, p).xyz;
  gl_FragColor = vec4 (col, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: You'll have better luck if you post a [mcve] that we can run instead of a few disconnected snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Sigh... it was a bit simpler than i thought.  answer provided here by JeremyDouglass

https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/comment/90488

solution:

"This problem isn't specific to shaders -- you would have the same problem if you were doing this with img(). You can't do clock math in this way. Multiplying anything by millis() will always create a scaling effect -- which in this case will always create what you call "scrubbing." For example, if you change the multiplier, 10 seconds suddenly becomes 15.

Instead, in order to change the speed at which the clock changes in the future but not to change how far it has advanced up-to-now, keep your own clock variable separate from millis(), and change the step amount (use addition, not multiplication) each draw frame. Now the speed at which the clock advances will change, but the base offset (the last clock time) won't jump around, because the original value isn't being scaled (multiplied)."